# Can I apply for a German registration certificate [Meldeschein] as a resident of a flat-share?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, housing, lease

I'm a U.S. software developer looking to re-locate to Berlin. I will be seeking a limited residence permit (*Aufenthaltserlaubnis*) which requires a local registration (*Meldeschein*.)

I understand that one must apply for the *Meldeschein* within 14 days of arrival in Berlin (this period varies by locality,) and to do so one must provide proof of German residence in addition to one's passport.

Articles which discuss this process frequently define such "proof of residence" as a lease or a rental contract.<sup>[1]</sup> I've found one in particular which expands on this criteria: "Rental agreement, lease, or confirmation letter."<sup>[2]</sup>

With the understanding that flat-shares often involve less formality than rents and sub-letting, my question is: **can I reasonably expect to apply for the *Meldeschein* as a resident of a *Wohngenmeinschaft* flat-share?**

Am I likely to find a WG which will include me in their rental agreement / contract / lease? Is there any difference between these, or do they just mean lease / lease / lease?

*Notes*

1. e.g., http://www.howtogermany.com/pages/residence.html
2. http://blog.mygermanexpert.com/2013/05/Anmeldung-at-the-Buergeramt.html

Comment: Yes.  Your WG will be able to give you a contract  ("Mietvertrag").

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

To register you need a confirmation from the landlord called "Wohnungsgeberbestätigung". You can find pre-prints [online](http://www.starnberg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/starnberg/redakteure/Aemter_A-Z/Einwohnermeldeamt/Wohnungsgeberbescheinigung.pdf), also [some in English](https://www.studentenwerk-wuerzburg.de/fileadmin/Daten/PDF_Wohnheime/Wohnungsgeberbest%C3%A4tigung/wohnen_wohnungsgeberbestaetigung_einzug_muster_en.pdf). With that form you register at the "Bürgerbehörde" or "Einwohnermeldeamt". It is definitely possible as part of a WG (shared flat), in fact I am registered that way right now. Just ask your landlord as soon as you sign the contract that you need the ceritification from them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you get the *[Wohnungsgeberbestätigung](https://allaboutberlin.com/images/wohnungsgeberbestaetigung.pdf)*. This document can be given by the main tenant, but the landlord must give his/her permission first. Without this document, you will not be able to register your address (and you're probably living in an illegal sublet).

During your Anmeldung, you must show your Wohnungsgeberbestätigung, the Anmeldung form and your ID. You can find more details about the Anmeldung process in Berlin [here](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/anmeldung-in-english-berlin).